# NTFS permissions: how to make a folder read only for a group, but give write permission for only one member of this group?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I've a folder that I want a group of users can have read-only access, but only one of these users must have write permissions.

The problem is that seems that if that user pertains to the read-only group, it takes preference over the write permission gave to the specific user...

Is not possible to remove the user from the group... so... how I can make this work?

Comment: Are you using groups to Deny access, or only to Allow access?

Comment: Look at the effective permissions for the user on the applicable folder. NTFS permissions are cumulative, so the least restictive permissions become the effective permissions. I suspect you've got something borked in the way that you've assigned permissions on this folder.

Comment: That's too simplistic. As mentioned elsethread, *explicit* rules override *implict or inherited* rules, but explicit **deny** rules will always override explicit **allow** rules.

Comment: Are you using Deny? If you are, you really shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NTFS permissions, Deny attributes overrule unset or Allow permissions. If the read-only group has write set to deny, no amount of allow rules from any other group membership will work.

There is an exception to this:

- Inherited Deny permissions do not prevent access to an object if the
  object has an explicit Allow permission entry. (Source: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736316%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Also, and this may or may not apply to your set up, Share permissions are also applied, and if a share's permissions aren't set to allow changes, the user still won't be able to write to the folder even with the correct NTFS permissions.

Comment: Not true. An explicit Allow will over-ride an inherited Deny. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736316(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Although you are right, I still think that wibbly's point has some good advice. Perhaps it should be edited...

Comment: @joeqwerty it is true in other situations. But we don't now if OP has set the deny explicitly or even if he has set any deny-settings.

Comment: I probably should add 'As a rule of thumb' to the beginning. Thanks Tom for editting :).

Answer (score 1):

When you have problem with a well-designed product/model then you should revise your work.

I remember old days of permission models debates and `role-based permission` is the best out of them after these many years.

Probably the user with `write` permission doesn't belong to this `read-only` group and role management should be revised.